# Rails urbanairship initialize - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, urbanairship.com

im trying to use Urbanairship gem to send notfication

I have a file located in 'config/initializers' that manage the notfications

The file is using a gem called 'Rufus' for scheduled task's , For the begging i want my Proggram to schedule and send task every day, this is what i tried so far:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require 'urbanairship'
s = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton
@segment_to_time = {'Israel' => Time.now.utc + 3.hours + 7.hours}

s.cron '00 00 * * *'  do
    UA = Urbanairship

    airship = UA::Client.new(key:'*Censored*', secret:'*Censored*')

    segment_list = UA::SegmentList.new(client: airship)

    segment_list.each do |segment|
        if (@segment_to_time.key?(segment['display_name']))

            # Scheudle morning notfication
            push = airship.create_push
            push.audience = UA.segment(segment)
            push.notification = UA.notification(alert: "Morning message")
            push.device_types = UA.all
            push.schedule = UA.scheduled_time(@segment_to_time[segment['display_name']])
            push.send_push
        end
    end
end
```

I keep getting the same error 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)' at the initialize of airship

What am i doing wrong?

thanks guys

Comment: If you think the issue is with the initialize on the airship client then don't check it in such complex scenario. 

Just open console in development and try to initialize. if it works. then your problem is somewhere else.

isolate the problem so you can move forward.

Comment: Also past the whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved your problem but I also ran into this problem when first getting urban airship installed. My problem was that I was using an older version of the gem.

> Version 3.0 is a major upgrade and backwards incompatible with earlier versions.
>
> To encourage the use of our SDK, which takes care of proper channel registration, support for device token registration has been removed. Support for v1 endpoints will also be removed and transitioned to their v3 equivalents where possible.

Source: https://github.com/urbanairship/ruby-library